# Renci.SshNet not working in SSIS 2016 script task

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2016, ssh.net

Using SQL Server 2016 (13.0.15000.23) & SSIS with VS 2015 Community with latest SSDT
I have a simple SSIS test package with 1 script task.
In that task I simply added a reference to Renci.sshnet  (2014.4.6.0) which is a .NET 4.0 DLL.
I change the project target framework to 4.0 
can make a basic call to create a connection:

```
Console.WriteLine("Start");

Renci.SshNet.ConnectionInfo ConnNfo = new   
Renci.SshNet.ConnectionInfo("hostOrIP", 22, "username",
       new AuthenticationMethod[]{

            // Pasword based Authentication
            new PasswordAuthenticationMethod("username","password"),

            // Key Based Authentication (using keys in OpenSSH Format)
            new PrivateKeyAuthenticationMethod("username",new PrivateKeyFile[]{
                new PrivateKeyFile(@"..\openssh.key","passphrase")
            }),
       }
   );
```

When I run it immediately get an DTS Script Task: Runtime Error
"Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation."

I have taken the code and made a stand alone console app out of it.. even 4.5 and it ran fine.

This whole thing worked fine with the exact same code in old server which had Sql Server 2008R2

I am missing something in the new config.  It will not run whenever I reference and use renci.sshnet

I also tried to but a breakpoint on the writeline and it does not get me there.. it fails before I can get to it..

Any ideas?  I am out of options.

Thanks in advance.

-Ken

Answer (score 2):

Apparently you have to add any referenced DLL to the GAC !!! yea.. forgot that.. this fixed it...ONLY from the admin run of the VS command prompt..

```
   D:\Flint\References>gacutil /i Renci.SshNet.dll
   Microsoft (R) .NET Global Assembly Cache Utility.  Version 4.0.30319.0
   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

   Assembly successfully added to the cache
```

Use this as a reference ... 
http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.ru/2011/05/referencing-custom-assembly-inside.html